# Symfony - Can't iterate on persistent collection

Tags: loops, twig, symfony-2.8

I'm stuck with persistent collection on which I can't loop in a Twig template because of "invalid argument supplied to foreach"..

Here's my entities

```
    Class Garage {
          /**
           * @ORM\OneToMany(
           *   targetEntity="my\Bundle\Entity\Car", 
           *   mappedBy="garageCar", 
           *   cascade={"persist"},   
           * )
           * @ORM\OrderBy({"carType" = "ASC"})
           * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
           */
           protected $car;


           public function __construct()
           {
               $this->car = new ArrayCollection();
           }

           //...
    }

    class Car{
            /**
             * @ORM\ManyToOne(
             *      targetEntity="my\Bundle\Entity\Garage",  
             *      inversedBy="car",
             *      cascade={"persist"}
             * )
             * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
             */
             private $garageCar;

             /**
              * @ORM\ManyToMany(
              *      targetEntity="my\Bundle\Entity\TypeCar",  
              *      cascade={"persist"}
              * )
              * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
              * @ORM\OrderBy({"position" = "ASC"})
              */
              private $typeCar;

              //.....
    }

    Class TypeCar {
          private $typeName;
          //...
    }
```

So here's how I want to set it :

Every garage can have 1 or many Car and 1 car always belong to 1 garage.

Every car can have multiple types .

My issue is when I want to loop over every cars, I got the error "Warning, invalid argument, supplied for foreach()"... line ..

here's this code  :

```
    {% for car in garage.car %}
        {{ dump(car) }}
         {#
               I still have to loop on car.carType but I cant even get the 1st loop to work..
         #}
    {% endfor %}
```

I my controller when I use get_class on my variable, it outputs that it's a PersistentCollection...
However I can't iterate on it...

Any idea ?

Comment: as i can see the problem is `@ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)` replace with `@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="garage_id", nullable=false)` 
Please check once column name or replace as per you table's, without column name they are unable to make any relations that's why records are coming blank to the relation
`name should be current table column and referencedColumnName column should be from the table on which you are trying to make a relation

Comment: to better understanding please go through http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: thanks for replying ! i'll take a look when as soon as i can